# What happens if some thread is executing some code from a .so and main thread tries to dlclose it?

Tags: linux, unix, shared-libraries, dlopen, dynamic-library

What happens if some thread is executing some code from a .so and main thread tries to dlclose it?

I am getting a segmentation fault during unloading an shared object. is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

**dlclose**() calls **munmap**() for the memory segment which being executed by thread and thus being read. Any read from such a memory leads to this fault, so it is expected and proper behavior.